# silent group not working in javascript regex match()

Tags: javascript, regex, match, silent

I'm trying to extract (potentially hyphenated) words from a string that have been marked with a '@'.

So for example from the string

```
var s = '@moo, @baa and @moo-baa are writing an email to a@bc.de'
```

I would like to return

```
['@moo', '@baa', '@moo-baa']
```

To make sure I don't capture the email address, I check that the group is preceded by a white-space character OR the beginning of the line:

```
s.match(/(^|\s)@(\w+[-\w+]*)/g)
```

This seems to do the trick, but it also captures the spaces, which I don't want:

```
["@moo", " @baa", " @moo-baa"]
```

Silencing the grouping like this

```
s.match(/(?:^|\s)@(\w+[-\w+]*)/g)
```

doesn't seem to work, it returns the same result as before. I also tried the opposite, and checked that there's no \w or \S in front of the group, but that also excludes the beginning of the line. I know I could simply trim the spaces off, but I'd really like to get this working with just a single 'match' call.

Anybody have a suggestion what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!!

[edit]

I also just noticed: Why is it returning the '@' symbols as well?! I mean, it's what I want, but why is it doing that? They're outside of the group, aren't they?

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem, just want to point out that `\w` won't work with non-latin characters, so it may be not safe to use it. Info here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich: That's ok, the string is limited to latin characters in this situation. Thanks for the reminder though!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the whole match is returned from `String.match` when using the "g" modifier. Because, with the modifier you are telling the function to match the whole expression instead of creating numbered matches from sub-expressions (groups). A global match does not return groups, instead the groups are the matches themselves.

In your case, the regular expression you were looking for might be this:

```
'@moo, @baa and @moo-baa are writing an email to a@bc.de'.match(/(?!\b)(@[\w\-]+)/g);
```

You are looking for every "@" symbol that doesn't follow a word boundary. So there is no need for silent groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to capture the space, don't put the `\s` inside of the parentheses. Anything inside the parentheses will be returned as part of the capture group.

Comment: You mean like this? match(/^|\s@(\w+[-\w+]*)/g)  That still returns the space and also doesn't capture the first occurrence in the line. Thanks though!